# How to return dereferenced value as a result of a function in Clojure

Tags: function, clojure, functional-programming

I have a atom with a vector value:

```
(def v (atom [1 2]))
```

I want to write a function that will return this dereferenced atom. That is, I basically want to write a function that will return the same result as this:

```
=> @v
[1 2]
```

My first take of this was something like this:

```
=> (let [f #(@v)]
     (println (f)))
ArityException Wrong number of args (0) passed to: PersistentVector  clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:429)
```

But this of course doesn't work as dereferenced atom is not a function:

```
=> (@v)
ArityException Wrong number of args (0) passed to: PersistentVector  clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:429)
```

The workaround I finally ended up with is this:

```
=> (let [f #(vec @v)]
     (println (f)))
[1 2]
nil
```

...but surely there must be a better way to do this that doesn't have to assume that value of atom is vector?

Comment: `(defn deref-v [] (deref v))`

Comment: That's just the `deref` function. I don't know why people wrap it in a function as an asnwer but anyway, you've mentioned in comments that it's a simplified question. I think you simplified too much so maybe edit and give us more details? as your question currently stands, `deref` *is* the function. And if you just use `deref` you don't pollute your namespace at all, and you can also just quickly `deref` using the `@` reader macro.

Comment: It's not just the `deref` function! It doesn't deref it's argument but `v`. FWIW, you could also write: `#(-> @v)`

Comment: @MasterMastic No, that's incorrect. As ClojureMostly said, `deref` is *not* equivalent to `(fn [] (deref v))`.

Comment: Oh I see, I thought it was a bit more general than that (although you also mentioned in the comments that you want to be able to pass to it different atoms?), but still I think you should be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the existing answers give the two simplest, most concise solutions, so here they are. As [stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38687414/5044950) by @Stefan, you want something equivalent to this function:

```
(fn [] (deref v))
```

However, this usage of [`deref`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/deref) is exactly the use case that the `@` reader macro is meant to simplify:

```
(fn [] @v)
```

Or, since `(deref v)` is a function call, you could instead use the `#()` reader macro:

```
#(deref v)
```

The main point here is that you can't use *both* `@` and `#()` *together* in this case. But that doesn't mean you can't or shouldn't use *one* of them.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is better to leave reader constructs like `#` and `@` out and just go with the functions (or macros and special forms):

```
user> (def v (atom [1 2]))
#'user/v
user> (let [f (fn [] (deref v))] (f))
[1 2]
```

I take it, that your example is a very simplified version of what you really want to do.  If not, `deref` may be just the function you are looking for.

Comment: (deref @v) instead of @v, brilliant! I knew there must be a simple solution. :) Yeah, it took me about a week or so to find out what my real problem was and come up with simplified example.

Comment: `(derev v)` not `(derev @v)`.  The `@` is just syntactic sugar for `deref` performed by the /reader/.  See the section on "Macro characters" on http://clojure.org/reference/reader

Comment: You are correct, I made a typo in my comment. Thanks for your answer, especially for reminding me that sometimes it's better to leave out # and @ and use functions themselves, as this is exactly the right situation for that.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to write a function that will return this dereferenced atom

```
(def v (atom [1 2]))
(defn foo [] @v)
(foo) ;;=> [1 2]
```

Comment: Yes! I wanted to go with anonymous function so that I don't pollute my namespace with function that is called only once, but your answer gave me idea to simply use expanded form of anon function: (let [f (fn [] @v)] (prn (f)))

Comment: @Domchi (let [f (fn [] @v)] (prn (f))) is effectively the same as (prn @v) - why the function?

Comment: It's a simplified example of a real use case. My use case is that I actually have a function that does something with an atom (in a go-loop), and I use it on different places by passing it different atoms.

Answer (score 1):

first of all: the reason of this error, is the expansion of lambda expression sugar syntax. You could think of it this way:

```
#(expression*) => (fn [] (expression*))
```

so, thinking this way:

`#(@v) => (fn [] (@v))` and `@v` in turn is expanded to `(deref v)` (easily seen with macroexpansion), that lead you to this form:

`(fn [] ((deref v)))`

In fact you are half right with the assumed reason of the error: the result of dereference is being called as a function, but in fact it could be (as vector has functional semantics), rather it just lacks a mandatory parameter (exactly what is said in the error text).
so it should work for this: `#(@v 0)` => `(fn [] ((deref v) 0))`

```
user> (let [f #(@v 0)]
        (println (f)))
1
nil
```

personally i would just go with a partial application, instead lambda expression to solve this:

```
user> (let [f (partial deref v)]
        (println (f)))
[1 2]
nil
```

Comment: I stand corrected - this is actually pretty cool, of course it expects the position in the vector as parameter. Thanks for explanation and the idea for partial; I'm always amazed to see how other people think about the same problem.